# How to keep the insertion point in a text input when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a program and I need the insertion point to go back to the text input when a button is clicked. Any ideas, thanks.

```html
<input type="text" name="fname" id="name">
 <p>
<button  id="go">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with JavaScript by attaching an event listener to the button. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ka4szvpy/).

```
<script>
var button = document.getElementById("go");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("name").focus();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are doing an async call and not loading another full page, otherwise this wouldn't be a relevant question.  Use the jquery focus method in your onclick event.  Here is a link with more info.

https://api.jquery.com/focus/

Answer (score 0):

For exactly what you're lookin' for, there's the [jQuery Caret (jCaret) plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCaret).
You can try out a demo [here](http://www.examplet.org/jquery/caret.php).